# API that provides common name aliases of famous people

Tags: api, search, linked-data

I'm looking for an API that provides common aliases for famous people.

For instance, "Hillary Clinton" would be associated with common appellations like "Hillary Rodham Clinton".

Comment: That's a bit broad. When talking about an API, you should at least name the programming language it should understand (and maybe some more details on your exact requirements). Alternatively: Speaking about a "resource", you could also check with our OpenData sister-site whether there might be a downloadable data-set you could work on locally (make sure to check with their `/help/on-topic` page first, as I'm not sure about their terms).

Comment: I edit the question as databases are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Wikidata provides such an API.

See for instance the Wikidata item for Hillary Clinton: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6294

[image]

The last column is what interests you.

You can get the information by calling a REST URL (with any programming language) and you get the result as JSON or TSV or other formats.

Free, unlimited, public domain.